# Stored procedure to get some rows and total

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I'm new in sql, so i need your help! I need a stored procedure to get a certain number of articles with some offset and total number of them to make pagination...
is this a correct code or there is a better way? How much queries will be executed, 1 for ctid, 1 for total and 1 for content data??

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `getArticles`(`offset` INT, `count` INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE ctid, total INT;
  SET ctid = (SELECT id FROM content_types WHERE name='article');
  SET total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM content WHERE content_type = ctid);  
  SELECT *, total FROM content 
    WHERE content_type = ctid 
    LIMIT count 
    OFFSET offset;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to leverage `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option and [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) function

> SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() can be useful in situations when
>   you want to restrict the number of rows that a query returns, but also
>   determine the number of rows in the full result set without running
>   the query again. An example is a Web script that presents a paged
>   display containing links to the pages that show other sections of a
>   search result. Using FOUND_ROWS() enables you to determine how many
>   other pages are needed for the rest of the result.

That being said your procedure might look like

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_articles(IN _offset INT, IN _count INT, OUT _total INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
    FROM content c JOIN content_types t 
      ON c.content_type = t.id
   WHERE t.name = 'article' 
    LIMIT _offset, _count;
  SET _total = FOUND_ROWS();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample usage:

```sql
SET @total = 0;
CALL get_articles(0, 3, @total);
SELECT @total;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbf92/3)** demo

Comment: thx for a such detailed answer, but i don't need a number of rows that a query returns. I need a data of content table with a limit of returning rows and total number of ALL rows.

Comment: You don't understand. `FOUND_ROWS()` when `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is included returns **exactly** what you asked - total number of **ALL** rows as if `LIMIT` wasn't applied to the query and it's faster then issuing another query even wrapped in a subquery. Take a look at working example provided.

Comment: sorry, did not read until the end... But i still need to make an additional request to get @total, did i understood correctly?

Comment: That's OK. It happens to the best of us :). Yes that's correct you need to issue the second select to read the session variable, but it's way lighter than executing full fledged query which most likely end-up to be a full-scan.

Comment: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS slow down the performance and also it's deprecated, is there any other alternative as i am aware of  window function count OVER() but it not works in older mysql version.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your lookin a query like this. Try to do everything in the same query, if it doesn't get too complex.

```
SELECT c.*, 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM content AS c1 WHERE c1.content_type = ct.id) AS total  
  FROM content AS c 
  INNER JOIN content_type AS ct ON c.content_type = ct.id
WHERE ct.name = 'article'
  LIMIT offset, count;
```